# How to submit data to server from android app with token and body?

Tags: java, android, curl, retrofit, android-api-levels

I am using retrofit for api calling.I need to send data to server from my application.The process is the server takes authentication(Header) token and the collection of data (Body) as parameter.I have coded the following part but it does not send the data to server.Please help me because i stuck on this since last 4 days.

**JAVA:**
//This method will be used to submit all the data into server for cash

```
public void submitData(final Integer customerID, final String zone, final Double due, final Double receivedAmount, final Integer typeID, final String paymentDate
    , final String remarks){
    //Adding the base URL
    String BASE_URL="api";
    ///Making a retrofit instance
    Retrofit retrofit=null;
    if (retrofit == null){
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setLenient()
                .create();
        retrofit=new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }
    CollectionData collectionData=new CollectionData(customerID,zone,due,receivedAmount,paymentDate,typeID,remarks);
    apiService=retrofit.create(AllApiService.class);
    final Call<CollectionData> userInformationCall=apiService.storeData("Bearer "+tokenSTR,collectionData);
    Log.v("URL",""+BASE_URL);
    Log.v("TOKEN ",""+tokenSTR);
    //handling user requests and their interactions with the application.
    userInformationCall.enqueue(new Callback<CollectionData>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<CollectionData> call, Response<CollectionData> response) {
                try{
                    Toast.makeText(context,"Successful",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
                catch (Exception e){
                    Log.v("EXCEPTION : ",""+e.getMessage());
                    Toast.makeText(context,"Slow server response",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<CollectionData> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(context,"Unsuccessful",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.v("ERROR : ",""+t.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

The server takes the data following way:

```
POST server_address HTTP/1.1
Host: host_name
Authorization: Bearer (token)
cache-control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 9a272ec4-87a3-4174-b5c5-a87ca478bce8
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="customer_id"

7

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="customer_zone"

Yellow

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="due"

0

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="received_amount"

0

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="collection_date"

26-01-2019

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="payment_type_id"

1

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="remarks"

Remarks
------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--
```

Comment: I would advise you to use RestTemplate, which enables you to send such a request with only a couple of lines. https://www.baeldung.com/rest-template

Comment: Thanks for your advice , i will obviously try to go on that way.